# Why does my Windows command line allow Linux commands?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

I hope this is not a glaringly obvious question since I couldn't Google anything about this, but I have just bought a new Windows laptop and realized that the command prompt could run Linux commands like `ls` and `scp`.

This is my PATH:

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

Is there something that I installed that allows this?  My friends are not able to do the same despite having the same OS.

Comment: There's a fair chance the commands are in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`.

Comment: You might even have a `which` command that will tell you where `ls` and `scp` live.  If not, you can always just list the files in the various directories in your path.  There' s really no need for someone on the Internet to give you guesses.

Comment: Alternatively try: `for %i in (ls.exe scp.exe) do @echo %~PATH:i`  (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050120-00/?p=36653)

Comment: @MichaelBurr: the Windows equivalent is `where`, he'll definitely have that one. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: well you learn something new every day. And it looks like it's been there since Win Server 2003 (but not in WinXP).  I've been installing some variant of `which` on Windows for so long, I guess I never bothered to check if they implemented it themselves (with a different name) at some point.  Maybe I'd have noticed if they just named it `which`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path like `...\mingw64\bin` allows linux commands;

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is port of GNU utilities on MS Windows